Issues passing params to BetaAnalyticsDataClient() function in Python (google.analytics.data_v1beta library) - Service Account
I have written a very simple piece of code in python for use in an azure function. It is meant to use my service account creds to run a report in google analytics 4 and return the results in JSON.
As this is running as an Azure Function, I am going to pass the code the json from the service account and use that to auth the ga client.
I used one of the quickstart samples from Google to try this out.
Unfortunately the BetaAnalyticsDataClient() function does not take the json as a parameter - rather the path to the JSON file, which is not a viable solution.
According to the documentation I can pass 'options' to the which include credentials like clientemail and private key parsed out of the JSON but no matter how I set that up I get a number of different errors.
Has anyone done this before and give me some tips? Please note it has been years since I have coded anything other the tsql and dax and other data related deliverables. If this is an easy answer I still appreciate the help! The google documentation is not easy to navigate.
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from google.analytics.data_v1beta import BetaAnalyticsDataClient
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import (
    DateRange,
    Dimension,
    Metric,
    MetricType,
    RunReportRequest,
)

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
viewid = '---redacted---'

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    keyfile = req.get_json() **#this is the JSON from the service account
**
    #clientemail = keyfile.get('client_email')
    #key = keyfile.get('private_key')
    #projectid = keyfile.get('project_id')
        
    try:
        response = get_report(key,clientemail,projectid)
        print_response(response)
        return func.HttpResponse(str(response),status_code=200)

    except Exception as e:
        logging.info(e)
        return func.HttpResponse(f"!! This HTTP triggered function executed unsuccessfully. \n\t",status_code=400)

def get_report(key,clientemail,projectid):
 
  client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient() **#NOT SURE WHAT I DO HERE - HOW DO I PASS THE OPTIONS SO IT AUTHENTICATES WITH THE SERVICE ACCOUNT INFO?**
  request = RunReportRequest(
     property="properties/{viewid}",
        dimensions=[Dimension(name="date"),Dimension(name="contentType")],
    metrics=[Metric(name="totalUsers"),Metric(name="screenPageViews"),Metric(name="screenPageViewsPerSession"),Metric(name="screenPageViewsPerUser"),Metric(name="averageSessionDuration")],
        date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date="7daysAgo", end_date="today")],
    )

  return client.run_report(request)


def print_response(response):

    print(f"{response.row_count} rows received")
    for dimensionHeader in response.dimension_headers:
        print(f"Dimension header name: {dimensionHeader.name}")
    for metricHeader in response.metric_headers:
        metric_type = MetricType(metricHeader.type_).name
        print(f"Metric header name: {metricHeader.name} ({metric_type})")

    print("Report result:")
    for rowIdx, row in enumerate(response.rows):
        print(f"\nRow {rowIdx}")
        for i, dimension_value in enumerate(row.dimension_values):
            dimension_name = response.dimension_headers[i].name
            print(f"{dimension_name}: {dimension_value.value}")

        for i, metric_value in enumerate(row.metric_values):
            metric_name = response.metric_headers[i].name
            print(f"{metric_name}: {metric_value.value}")


always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

sometimes functions allow to use file-like object instead of filename and it allows to use io.String("your text") as  file-like object

you can always get source code for BetaAnalyticsDataClient() and use it to create own function which can get text instead filename
